# React Gatsbyjs add class to gatsby-image based on aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

gatsby-image wraps each image with a gatsby-image-wrapper div which fills 100% of the available viewport width. This wrapper div can easily be styled with CSS but **there is no way to treat landscape, portrait or square images differently from each other.**

[image: like this example] What if, you wanted to have landscape images fill 80%-100% of the available width but have portrait and square images fill no more than 40-50% of the viewport width.

So ideally each gatsby-image-wrapper div gets a class added depending on its aspect ratio, which would be either; `landscape`, `portrait` or `square`.

One way to do this could be to write some conditional statement using the aspect ratio that comes with childImageSharp:

```
      edges {
        node {
          name
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 915, quality: 90) {
              aspectRatio
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

When I map over all my gallery images, I can grab the aspect ratio and add it to each gatsby-image-wrapper using className but it's not very useful in its raw format as the returned data for aspectRatio are numbers like `0.6666666666666666` for portrait images or `1.5003750937734435` for landscape. Having those classes mentioned above would be better to work with; `landscape`, `portrait` or `square`.

This is how I'm getting all my gallery images from the current post, along with their `aspectRatio`.

```
export default ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <article>
        {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node }, index) => (
          <div>
            <Img
              key={index}
              className={node.childImageSharp.fluid.aspectRatio}
              alt={node.name}
              fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid}
            />
            <span>{node.childImageSharp.fluid.aspectRatio}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </article>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

The full GraphQL query I am using is:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!, $absolutePathRegex: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        date
        modified
        caption
        description
        cover {
          publicURL
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 915, quality: 90) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
      fields {
        slug
      }
    }
    allFile(
      filter: {
        extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(png)|(tif)|(tiff)|(webp)|(jpeg)/" }
        absolutePath: { regex: $absolutePathRegex }
      }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 915, quality: 90) {
              aspectRatio
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

There must be a simple solution to this using a conditional statement in React where you map over all your images, take the aspect ratio
and then convert the raw data to the desired classes.

So instead of:

```
<div class="1.5003750937734435 gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="0.6666666666666666 gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="0.6666666666666666 gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="1.0000000000000000 gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="1.5003750937734435 gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
```

You'd get:

```
<div class="landscape gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="portrait gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="portrait gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="square gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="landscape gatsby-image-wrapper"></div>
```

Which could then be easily styled with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, aren't you already 99% there? You can write your conditional inside of the `map`, or better yet, write a component that wrap `<Img>`:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

// we only care about `aspectRatio`, the rest will be passed directly to `Img`
// also take out `className` so it be merged with our generated `orientation` class name
const ImgWithOrient = ({ aspectRatio, className, ...props }) => {
  let orientation
  if (aspectRatio > 1) orientation = 'landscape'
  if (aspectRatio < 1) orientation = 'portrait'
  else orientation = 'square'

  return <Img className={`${className} ${orientation}`} {...props} />
}

export default ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <article>
        {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node }, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <ImgWithOrient
              key={index}
              aspectRatio={node.childImageSharp.fluid.aspectRatio}
              className="other class name"
              alt={node.name}
              fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid}
            />
            <span>{node.childImageSharp.fluid.aspectRatio}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

---

Also note that when you loop over something, you'd need to put `key` in the most outer component -- in this case, the outer `<div>`, instead of `<Img>`.

Comment: Thanks Derek, your answer got this working. I had to play around with the less/greater than operators a bit to get the desired outcome. This is what I have based on your code: ```const ImgWithOrient = ({ aspectRatio, className, ...props }) => {
  let orientation;
  if (aspectRatio >= 1.2) orientation = "landscape";
  if (aspectRatio <= 0.8) orientation = "portrait";
  if (aspectRatio > 0.8 && aspectRatio < 1.2) orientation = "square";

  return <Img className={`${className} ${orientation}`} {...props} />;
};```